# Send array in http Post request Android

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I want to send string array data via post request to server from android. request parameters should be like this string array e.g.

["56e7e4ade","56e7e435ade"]

I am sending with this

```
for(int i=0; i<connectedpeople.size(); i++)
    {
      nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myarray[]", connectedpeople.get(i).getObjectId()));
    }
```

But that doesnt work. can anybody give suggetion to this?

Comment: Why sending array when you can send it as comma separated string

Comment: But How? what should be request entity     ?                      httpPost.setEntity(" ?? ");

Comment: @RavjitSingh thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used simple JsonArray to post data and its worked. No need to use namevalue pairs or JsonObject.

```
JSONArray myarray = new JSONArray();
 for(int i=0;i<favoritesUserList.size(); i++){
     myarray.put(favoritesUserList.get(i).getObjectId());
 }
new getUserData().execute(myarray);
```

Thanks a lot Guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSONArray` instead . cheers :)

```
JSONArray jArry=new JSONArray();
for(int i=0; i<connectedpeople.size(); i++) {
    jArry.put(connectedpeople.get(i).getObjectId());
}
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myarray",jArry.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

/** Format it according to your requirement **/

```
RequestParams parameter = new RequestParams();
 ArrayList<YourModelClass> yourSelectedArrayList=new ArrayList();//fill `this array according to your requirement`
 JSONObject jsonObject=null;
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
 for (int i = 0; i < yourSelectedArrayList.size(); i++) {
                   jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    try {

                        jsonObject.put("truckType",yourSelectedArrayList.get(i).getName());

                        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

parameter.put("",jsonArray.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

            for(int i=0; i<connectedpeople.size(); i++)
            {
               param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myarray", connectedpeople.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
```